# How to pass different error code for validations using hibernate validators?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, hibernate-validator

I am using hibernate validators to implement validations in my application. I have also used custom annotations and custom validators for business validation requirements. It is working fine and I am able to get the specific error messages as per the implementation. But, now i also want to return error code (something like given in below code snippet) along with error message for each of the validations to the method where validate method is called.

I have read the documentation for hibernate validations but couldn't find anything for this requirement. Can some one please help me to implement error codes in this scenario.

```
@ValidStateInCountry(code=006, message="Invalid state for given country")
@ValidZipInCountry(code=007, message="Invalid zip for given country")
public class  Address {

@NotBlank(code=001, message="address line is mandatory")
private String addressLine;

@ValidCountry(code=002, message="Invalid Country name")
@NotBlank(code=003, message="Country name is mandatory")
private String country;

@NotBlank(code=004, message="state is mandatory")
private String state;

@NotBlank(code=005, message="zip is mandatory")
private String zipCode;

}
```

Comment: A good question. Have you tried this approach?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2911486/3368818

Comment: @J Woodchuck : Yes I have tried but it will not work in my case..i have multiple class level and property level custom validators and I need separate error codes for each validation failure.

Answer (score 0):

First, we don't support that for the built-in constraints so you will have to reimplement them yourselves to add this feature.

Second, I think what you need is what we call a dynamic payload that you can attach to the `ConstraintViolation` when creating it in your `ConstraintValidator`. Then you can unwrap the violation to the Hibernate Validator-specific flavor of it and make use of it. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-dynamic-payload for a complete example.

You can extract the error code from the annotation once by implementing `initialize()`: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/beanvalidation-api/blob/2.0.2/src/main/java/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.java#L50 .